# UPDATE with CASE with 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables and I want to update `table2` with criteria of `table1` and `table2`. 
The criteria are:

1.`table1.amount > 10000`

2.`table2.flag` is null or `table2.flag = '0'`

So if the 2 conditions are true, then update `table2.flag = '1'` and `table2.flagdate = getdate()`

`table2.flag` is a flag to check everyone who pays more than 10,000. But if already flagged, I don't want to flag again because I can't loose the original `table2.flagdate`. But I try a lot of things, nothing works the way I want. Any ideas?

Comment: How are table1 and table2 related?

Comment: There is an ID. table1.id = table2.id

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE t2 
  SET flag = 1, flagdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  FROM dbo.table2 AS t2
  INNER JOIN dbo.table1 AS t1
  ON t2.id = t1.id
  WHERE t1.amount > 10000 
    AND (t2.flag IS NULL OR t2.flag = 0);
```

You can avoid the `OR` condition if you change the `flag` column to `NOT NULL` with default `0`.